# Make multiple canvas or overlay drawings on the same canvas html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need your advice, I have a html with canvas, in this html you can add circles and then link these to make a figure, I also want to insert a search where you can find the different figures and focussed on it, so I don't know if it'll be better : to overlay the figures or use different canvas for each figure.
(I'm not implement the search function yet.)
What do you think?

Here is the functions that makes de draws

//this function puts the circles on a `<table>`, and then the other function takes the img coordinates and link it making a figure.

```
function position(year, mon)
{
    $('#' + year + ' .' + mon).prepend('<img class="black_point" src="./images/circle.png"/>');
}

     var table = document.getElementById("tabla");
        var images = table.getElementsByTagName("img");  
        var canvas = document.getElementById("miCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var x,y; // Remember coordinates

        canvas.width  = table.offsetWidth;
        canvas.height = table.offsetHeight;

        function connect(image, index) { //this function link the images
            var tabBcr = table.getBoundingClientRect();
            var imgBcr = image.getBoundingClientRect();
            x = imgBcr.left + (imgBcr.width / 2) - tabBcr.left;
            y = imgBcr.top + (imgBcr.height / 2) - tabBcr.top;
            index === 0 ? ctx.moveTo(x, y) : ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        }

        //this function add a new canvas
        function figure(){
         /*$('#miCanvas').prepend('<canvas id="myCanvas">Su navegador no soporta Canvas.</canvas>');
         //this is the property who overlay the figures
         cxt.globalCompositeOperation="source-over";/*
  //which it will be better to implement a search function?
        }

        // new path here
        ctx.beginPath();

        for(var i=0; i<images.length; i++){ 
          connect( images[i], i);  // provide index so we can sep. move/line
        }

        // then at the end:
        ctx.fill();
```

Comment: I have already paste it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use 1 html canvas to hold all your connected circles.**

This simplifies the event handling when focusing / blurring your figures.

You can test if the mouse is inside one of your circles like this:

```
// given a circle defined by centerX, centerY, radius
var dx = mouseX - centerX;
var dy = mouseY - centerY;
var isInside = dx*dx+dy*dy <= radius*radius;
```

**Here's an outline of how to focus on a figure:**

1. Create a javascript object defining each circle. If a set of objects makes up a figure, then add a `group` property to each circle-object representing which group that circle is a member of.
2. Put all your circle-objects in an array.
3. In your mouse event handlers, iterate through the circle-objects-array and find which circle is under the mouse. That circle's `group` has been focused.

Comment: But I want to check if the mouse is over the figure forming circles

Comment: I've added outline to my answer explaining how to group circles into a figure.

Comment: How can I know if a group of objects makes up a figure?

Comment: @AliATriple. You say your code will "add circles and then link these to make a figure,"  so each of those linked circles will be given, for example: `group:'figure1'` Then if the mouse handler finds one of those circles with a test like this: `if(targetedCircle.group=='figure1')...`,  then you will know that the 'figure1' circles are targeted.